# Finite languages $L\in RE$

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, regular-languages

I want to check if I understood it in the right way.
In some example where $L\in RE$ the explanation deal with 2 cases: 1st when $L$ finite and 2nd when $L$ infinite. In the second case $L\in R$, isn't? Is it possible somehow that $L\in RE\setminus R$ be finite?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. For example, I don't understand what you mean by "The second case is ∈, isn't?". Regarding the last question, every finite language is regular and thus decidable.

Comment: Thanks @BaderAbuRadi, I edited the question is it clear now?

Comment: Sorry, it is still unclear.  Are you asking: 1) whether every infinite recognizable language $L$ is in $R$? 2) whether there are finite languages in $RE\setminus R$?

Comment: Whether there are finite languages in ∖?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. [Every finite language is regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/104322/why-is-every-finite-language-a-%E2%8A%86-%CE%A3-regular), and thus decidable. Therefore the existence of a finite language $L$ in $ \text{RE} \setminus \text{R}$ is impossible. However, note that there languages $L$ in $\text{RE}\setminus \text{R}$ (e.g., $Halt_{TM}$), and by what we have seen previously, such languages have to be infinite.